# strange behavior of gtk.FileChooserDialog.get_current_folder()

Tags: python, gtk

I have a very weird problem at the moment and I hope you'll be able to reproduce it. Please try the following Python code:

```
import gtk


print '=== 1 ==='

def _createFileDialog():
    dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog()
    print dialog.get_current_folder(), '***'
    dialog.set_current_folder('/home/')
    print dialog.get_current_folder(), '###'

dialog = _createFileDialog()


print '=== 2 ==='

dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog()
print dialog.get_current_folder(), '***'
dialog.set_current_folder('/home/')
print dialog.get_current_folder(), '###'
```

As you can see, the code sections are basically the same, so you might expect the same results. However, during the first section, the line ending with '###' prints 'None ###', while the second section correctly prints '/home ###'.
I re-tried this on two different computers of my colleagues, and on one computer this was reproducable. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Nice greetings and thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 2):

It can also print "None ###" in both cases.

The call to `set_current_folder` seems to be asynchronous, it works as expected if you let  GTK handle pending events before calling `get_current_folder`:

```
dialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog()
print dialog.get_current_folder(), '***'
dialog.set_current_folder('/home/')

while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()

print dialog.get_current_folder(), '###'
```